# Sybase get last record of record group

Tags: sql, sybase-asa

I have a table like this

id     ref    status    date

1     150     P     10/01/2010
2     150     P     11/01/2010
3     150     P     12/01/2010
4     151     P     10/01/2010
5     151     C     NULL
6     152     P     11/01/2010
7     152     P     12/01/2010
8     152     C     NULL

And what i want is to retrieve all the records that either have a status equals to **C** and (for those who have the status **P**) the last record according to the column date.

For example:

id     ref    status    date

3     150     P     12/01/2010
5     151     C     NULL
8     152     C     NULL

So far I have tried to do subquerys but i dont get to have the last record according to date.

I´m using Sybase 8.0.2.4542. Thank you so much guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the solution:

```
select id, ref, status, max(date)
from table 
where status = 'P'
group by id, ref, status, date
union all
select id, ref, status, date
from table 
where status = 'C'
```

with one query:

```
select *from 
(select id, ref, status, max(date)
from table 
where status = 'P'
group by id, ref, status, date
union all
select id, ref, status, date
from table 
where status = 'C') RES
```

Comment: That works great!! Thank you so much!! If I want to query over the resulting dataset how could I achieve this?  I'm trying using **SELECT * FROM (-YOUR ANSWER-) AS RES** But it throws a syntax error at the beginning

Comment: This is what im doing **from(
    (select id, ref, status, max(date) from table  where status = 'P' group by id, ref, status, date)
union all
    (select id, ref, status, date from table where status = 'C')
) The error shown is _Could not execute statement. Syntax error near ')'. SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000"_

Comment: I added one more solution, try it please.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried your solution and also added this select *from 
(select id, ref, status, max(date)
from table 
where status = 'P'
group by id, ref, status, date
union all
select id, ref, status, date
from table 
where status = 'C') RES (id,ref,status,date).  Apparently it needs a columns specification when giving an alias. Anyway thank you so much!!

Comment: @CristianAlejandroHurtadoRom I'm glad I could help you. Don't forget you can vote for the answer :)